# ¿Crear aplicación de escritorio y aplicación móvil usando HTML, CSS y JavaScript (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css, app

Buenas amigos, espero que me ayuden en esta consulta. Estoy buscando la manera de crear una aplicación de escritorio y móvil usando tecnología web. (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). Me recomendaron Electron.atom.io para la de escritorio. Lo que deseo como tal es que casi el mismo código y diseño se implemente para la app movil, desktop y web. Una aplicación que vi que esta desarrollado con electron es "DISCORD", que es un chat. y la he usado tanto para web, movil y desktop y es excelente. Esta desarrollada con Electron. Espero haber sido claro y que me ayuden. Buen dia. Saludos. y Gracias.

Comment: Te recomendaria ver el proyecto de [Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) es un editor de textos de adobe, es lo que quieres HTML + CSS+ JS para escritorio, quiza te pueda ayudar

Comment: Lo que deseo realizar es solo para visualizar unos datos que estan en una bd sqlite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si amigo http://electron.atom.io/ es lo mejor para eso, en cambio si necesitas una que tenga db te recomiendo basel que es una variante de electron.

En fin Electron lo que hace es levantar un chromiun y ejecutar tu pagina.
Saludos

aqui te dejo un ejemplo de una app que yo hice con electron. https://github.com/AlexisNichel/MedicalHistory.git

Comment: Revisando tu comentario entonces puedo usar Electron o Basel. Esto es para escritorio, ahora para movil usando tecnologia web que me recomiendas?

Comment: si usas electron pues para movil usa ionic o ionic2 (ésto dependiendo si sabes angular o angular2) ya que tambien es en java script al igual que electron

Comment: tambien puedes usar xamarim que es en el lenguaje c#

Comment: pero sea como sea tendrás que hacer cambios en la aplicacion para usarla en ionic y en electron, solo que será mucho mas fácil y rápida

Comment: lei que trabajas con sqlite, definitivamenta basel (que es electron pero con sqlite) e ionic para moviles te seran buena opcion

Answer (score 1):

Amigo no es posible hacer un solo desarrollo que te realice las 3 aplicaciones ya que como te comentan anteriormente te dispara un tipo navegador con la pagina que desarrolles y la misma se usa para el mobile. te recomiendo que valides las necesidades de tu aplicación móvil, desktop y web ya que si necesitas utilizar funciones del teléfono necesitaras un desarrollo nativo, si necesitas utilizar funciones del desktop no podrás desde la pagina web y si necesitas realizar peticiones web se te complicara por la multi plataforma que deseas crear.

si es solo un desarrollo sencillo pues electron es tu mejor opción. si es un desarrollo que requiere actividades especiales del teléfono, desktop y web tendrías que hacer desarrollos por separado.

Comment: Ok amigo, esta bien, no hay problema. ahora bien. que me recomiendas para cada caso?

Comment: Bueno dependiendo de lo que necesites hacer amigo. recuerda que se tiene que adaptar a tus necesidades. si la aplicación utilizara funciones del telefono te recomiendo el lenguaje nativo de la plataforma a desarrollar o puedes utilizar cordova si utilizaras un framework ya que interactua con las API de todo tipo de dispositivos moviles. para Desktop puedes utilizar java o C# y para web Laravel o CakePHP. o si tienes visual estudio MVC C# todo depende de tus necesidades y tus conocimientos en esos lenguajes. Quedo a la disposicion para ayudarte

Comment: Si bien cada aplicación tiene sus requisitos, si ésta no amerita usar exhaustivamente la API del SO, como ocurre en el 90% de los casos, entonces, no hay problema en absoluto en usar Electron. El pero que tiene Electron corresponde a aplicaciones de alto rendimiento; si es el caso, mejor usa algo nativo como Qt.

Respecto a lo móvil, **se puede crear apps nativas usando JavaScript, HTML y CSS**, ReactNative compila eso a código Java, ObjectiveC o C# (React Windows permite compilar a UWP).

Comment: Amigo si la respuesta te ha sido de ayuda por favor marca tu voto o correcta la respuesta. Muchisimas Gracias.